# Alternate method for PIVOT - IN with sub-query support

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

As per oracle documentation, `PIVOT` function doesn't support sub-query in the "`IN`" clause but it is possible in the `PIVOT` XML function.
E.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
PIVOT
(
  SUM(column_name_1)
  FOR [column_name_2] IN (['Output_Column1'],['Output_Column2'])
)
AS aliasName
```

I need to replace the `['Output_Column1'],['Output_Column2']` with sub-query.

Is there some other function equivalent to `PIVOT` where we can supply sub-query instead hard coding the entire output columns or even in the `PIVOT` function itself?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the number of columns must be known at parse time. For PIVOT XML there is no problem because such query returns only one column.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. But is there any equivalent function like PIVOT and fulfilling the above criteria(Using sub-query)?

Comment: @VijayKrish My comment was about any SQL query - you cannot have variable number of columns, there is no such option. Maybe explain what you are trying to achieve. Why do you need such thing?

Comment: The status hold values like "Completed" and "Failed". In future status column may have "Incomplete" as value.
My Existing query is `code` SELECT *  FROM   (select count(status) cnt, status from tableName where 
lower(person_id) = lower('person_id') group by status)
PIVOT (SUM(cnt)
FOR status IN ('COMPLETED','FAILED'))
So, as i said if "INCOMPLETE" value added in future in have to modify the sql.

Comment: Hence I'm looking for something like `code` 
SELECT *  FROM   (select count(status) cnt, status from tableName where 
lower(person_id) = lower('person_id') group by status)
PIVOT (SUM(cnt)
FOR status IN (select dictinct(status) from dashboard))
Thanks in advance